# What happens to FILE pointer after file is closed?

Tags: c, file, fclose

I wish to know what happens to FILE pointer after the file is closed. Will it be NULL?

Basically, I want to check if a file has already been closed before closing a file.

For example as follows:

```
FILE *f;

if(f!=NULL)
{
  fclose(f);
}
```

Can I do this or is there any other way to go about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since arguments are passed by value there is not way `fclose` could set your file pointer to `NULL`. Since `fclose` probably destroys the `FILE` you have to

- Manually set the file pointer to `NULL` after doing a `fclose` (won't work if you close it in a different function unles you use `FILE **`)
- Don't end up in a situation where you "*forget*" whether you closed it or not (might be tricky)

Comment: In that case, how can i find out if the file has already been closed or not.

Answer (score 8):

[Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/quotations.html) quotes [Auguste Comte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_Comte) (1798-1857):

```
  "Nothing is destroyed until it is replaced"
```

You could use the macro:

```
  #define fclose(fp)  ((fp) ? fclose(fp) : 0, (fp) = 0)
```

This fixes ***two*** different and opposing problems:

- The `FILE *` pointer is NULL'd after `fclose`, so it can't be
  `fclose'd` twice.
- This version of `fclose` *will* accept a NULL argument. Many common
  versions of `fclose`--such as those in HPUX, SGI, and CYGWIN--are happy
  with NULLs. It is odd that the FreeBSD-inspired versions such as in Linux,
  and Microsoft, aren't.

Of course, the macro introduces its own problems:

- It doesn't return the proper error value. But if you wanted to see
  this, you can disable the macro with extra parentheses, as in: `if
  ((fclose)(fp) == EOF){ /* handle error... */ }`
- It doesn't have *function semantics*, as it uses its argument
  multiple times. But it is hard to imagine this causing a problem. But you can use `(fclose)`. Or name it `FCLOSE`, to follow convention.

Answer (score 3):

FILE * It's a pointer to a FILE structure, when you call fclose() it will destroy/free FILE structure but will not change the value of FILE* pointer means still it has the address of that FILE structure which is now not exits.

same things happem with any pointer getting with malloc

```
int a malloc(10);
free(a);
```

still a will not be NULL

in most case i always do this things

```
free(a);
a=NULL;
```

Edit: you can not check whether its CLOSED/freed at any time. just to make sure you can assign it NULL after free/fclose so you can check its NULL or not and go ahead ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. and better way is to set `fp` to `NULL` 
else

it will be dangling pointer (a pointer which is pointing to something which it does not own or which does not exist)