# umask not working in c code

Tags: c, umask

I have made a c code intended to create a file at root directory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

const char *path="/";
int main(){
    FILE *fp;
    umask(0);
    chdir(path);

    fp=fopen("test.txt","w+");
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

the compilation gives no errors but when I execute the file, the following error appears:

```
kwagjj@kwagjj-Inspiron-3420:~$ gcc -Wall a2.c -o a2
kwagjj@kwagjj-Inspiron-3420:~$ ./a2
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

how am I using the `umask` function wrong?

Comment: How do you know the segmentation fault is caused by `umask`?

Comment: Use gdb to get the backtrace and add it to your question

Comment: @YuHao uh, your right... I guess the error is basically not because of `umask` but I was assuming that the problem is eventually related to `umask` because I intended `umask` to give the proper permission to fopen and fclose

Comment: You should check if `fopen` returns `NULL` or not.

Comment: You/your program (probably) does not have permission to create files in the "/" (root) directory.  So, what are the permission for "/" and is your program being executed via 'sudo'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My money is on `fopen()` failing (probably due to insufficient permissions) and returning `NULL`, and `fclose(NULL)` [causing the segfault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922871/why-glibcs-fclosenull-cause-segmentation-fault-instead-of-returning-error).

Comment: then how can I get the proper permission? I used the `umask` to get the permission but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @kwagjj `umask` doesn't affect whether your program has the permission to do something. It affects the default permission bits when your program creates files.

Comment: @NPE thanks I understand what you are trying to say... I've moved on and am trying another way to get the job done