# If file pointer is null, do I have to use fclose()? (C)

Tags: c

When I open a file in C, I am currently doing this:

```
int main()
{
   FILE *f
   f = fopen("employers.dat", "rb");
   if(f == NULL)
   {
       PUTS("can not open the file:\"employers.dat\"");
       fclose(f);
       exit(-1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Is it necessary to use `fclose` if the pointer is `NULL`?

Comment: How would `fclose` know which file to close if there is **no** valid file descriptor?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not only it is **not** necessary to use `fclose()` when `f` is `NULL`, but you should actually **not** invoke `fclose()` when `f` is `NULL`.

1. If `f` is `NULL`, then the file was never opened to begin with, so it does not need any closing.
2. Even if the file somehow needed closing, the solution could not possibly involve passing `NULL` to `fclose()`, because a `NULL` parameter carries absolutely no information that `fclose()` can use to figure out which file to close.
3. I am not sure whether `fclose()` contains extra code for detecting and ignoring an erroneous `NULL` parameter passed to it, but even if it does, it is best to not tempt your fate.

Comment: Related to closing a NULL file handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922871/why-glibcs-fclosenull-cause-segmentation-fault-instead-of-returning-error

Comment: fclose() an NULL pointer is undefined behavior, and common implementations simply crash the program if you do that.

Comment: I think I have seen gcc implementations able to do that, but since it's not standard, yes, we should not rely on that

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is not opened there is no need to close the file.

Comment: You can savely free(NULL) but I cannot find any documentation which says, it is safe to do that for fclose(NULL).

Comment: @BitTicker No it's not. `fclose(NULL)` is undefined behavior. But indeed I can't find  a way to support that assertion either.

Comment: MSVC documentation says *"If `stream` is `NULL`, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, `fclose` sets `errno` to `EINVAL` and returns `EOF`. It is recommended that the stream pointer always be checked prior to calling this function."*

Comment: @WeatherVane Interesting, it might just be implementation defined. The standard says nothing about it. With *glibc* a program calling `fclose(NULL)` would usually cause a `SIGSEGV` signal.