# (linux) "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" while passing an char pointer into funtion in c

Tags: c, linux, pointers, char, arguments

I'm having always the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"" every time I try this a function:

```
int CheckFile(char * filename){
    FILE * bd = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(bd == NULL){
        fclose(bd);
        return -1;
    }else{
        fclose(bd);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

function calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DEFAULT_FILE_NAME "file.txt"

int CheckFile(char * filename);

int main(int argc, char ** argv[]){
    char * name_of_file == NULL;

    if(argc > 1){
        printf("argc > 1\n");
        for(i=0;argc>i;i++){
            if(strcmp(argv[i],"-f")==0){
                name_of_file = argv[i+1];
                if(CheckFile(name_of_file) != 0)
                    printf("Can't find the file "%s".", name_of_file);
                }
    if(name_of_file == NULL){
        if(CheckFile(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME) != 0);
            printf("Can't find the default file \""DEFAULT_FILE_NAME"\".");
    }
}
```

By my troubleshoots I would say the problem is on "char * filename", but can't find a way out of this. Can someone give me a hand? I would be thankful.

Comment: try `const char * filename`

Comment: also don't `fclose(bd);` if bd is null.

Comment: Does your compiler really compile this? `int main(int argc, char ** argv[])`  There should be some warning about wrong level of indirection for `argv[i]`

Comment: and don't do `name_of_file = argv[i+1];` if `i==argc-1` :)

Comment: It's time to learn some [basic debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Run your program in a debugger and it should at least tell you *where* the SEGFAULT happens. Then you can find out *WHY*

Comment: Please also provide all the important information: What input do you provide? How do you call your program?

Comment: This can't be your real code. It can't compile...

Comment: `char * name_of_file == NULL;` ? Sure about the `==`

Comment: Writing `for(i=0;argc>i;i++){` is a cackhanded, unorthodox way of writing `for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {`.  This is the conventional notation for a `for` loop counting from `0` up to a limit (`argc` in this case).  Other problems have been pointed out to you in comments and answers (including that you probably need `for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {` in the context of your program, which does not visibly define/declare `i`).

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't compile properly.  The definition of `main()` is wrong:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv[]) {
```

It needs to be

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
```

Also this

```
char * name_of_file == NULL;
```

Needs to be

```
char * name_of_file = NULL;
```

Because we're doing initialization here, not comparison.

Also, that print doesn't compile for me either:

```
printf("Can't find the file "%s".", name_of_file);
```

It seems like your escape sequences/format specifiers got mangled somehow. Try

```
printf("Can't find the file %s.", name_of_file);
```

Instead.

Next, `i` isn't defined. Do you have it as a global variable that you haven't shown in your snippet? Either way you can just put it here:

```
for (int i = 0; argc > i; i++) {
```

instead of

```
for(i=0;argc>i;i++){
```

Also, this `if` here does nothing:

```
if(CheckFile(DEFAULT_FILE_NAME) != 0);
```

Because of that semicolon at the end, you probably want to remove that.

Last but not least, there are two `}` missing at the end of your `main` function.

It seems like you have problems with debugging your code. Consider using an IDE that will show you compilation errors. Also, you should not try to `fclose` the file if it didn't open (`fopen` returning `NULL`).

Comment: the "char * name_of_file == NULL;" was my mistake coping the code.

Answer (score 1):

This has undefined behavior and should be expected to crash or worse:

```
if(bd == NULL){
    fclose(bd);
```

A null pointer is not a valid argument to `fclose`. Just remove the call to `fclose` there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674141/if-file-pointer-is-null-do-i-have-to-use-fclose-c  (also the second comment to this post :))

Comment: noted and changed! thanks ;)