# Why "%79[^\n]\n" is causing a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, gdb

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
        char line[80];
        FILE *in = fopen("spooky.csv", "r");
        FILE *file1 = fopen("ufos.csv", "w");
        FILE *file2 = fopen("disappearances.csv", "w");
        FILE *file3 = fopen("others.csv", "w");
        while (fscanf(in, "%79[^\n]\n", line) == 1) {
                if (strstr(line, "UFO"))
                        fprintf(file1, "%s\n", line);
                else if (strstr(line, "Disappearance"))
                        fprintf(file2, "%s\n", line);
                else
                        fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line);
        }
        fclose(file1);
        fclose(file2);
        fclose(file3);
        return 0;
}
```

This code is returning a runtime error of segmentation fault.

[image]

Does it matter on what hardware I'm compiling this program? I'm using a Fedora 38 (Workstation) with Intel Core i7 (7th Gen).

Comment: You don't check that the files were opened successfully.

Comment: You have to test if the files are correctly opened, E.G. `if (in == null)  perror("Error")`. Instead of `fscanf` you might use `fgets()` ( https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets ) that reads till the first `\n`. Also the file `in` should be closed!

Comment: Where you close the files it would be better to use: `if (file1 != null) fclose(file1);`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32674141/if-file-pointer-is-null-do-i-have-to-use-fclose-c/32674233#32674233

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the `fscanf` format: as indicated in the error message, the argument `s` to the internal function `__vfscanf_internal` has the value `0x0` indicating a null pointer passed for the `FILE *` argument.

You should check for `fopen` failure to open the files and report this condition with a meaningful error message.

Also note these remarks:

- you should close `in`.
- you could use `fgets()` instead of the `fscanf()` format.
- the `fscanf` format will fail converting an initial empty line in **spooky.csv**, which should not occur if it is an actual CSV file.
- the trailing `\n` in the conversion specification will cause the newline to be consumed along with any initial white space in the next line, which may not be intended. Use `%79[^\n]%*[\n]` to avoid this, yet consume subsequent empty lines.
- the cde will silently break long lines into chunks of 79 bytes. Modifying the code for arbitrary long lines is non trivial, but a larger buffer might be a good option.
- you might want to special case the first line if it is expected to be a header line with the field names.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE *fopen_check(const char *filename, const char *mode) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s: %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    return fp;
}

int main(void) {
    char line[80];

    FILE *in = fopen_check("spooky.csv", "r");
    FILE *file1 = fopen_check("ufos.csv", "w");
    FILE *file2 = fopen_check("disappearances.csv", "w");
    FILE *file3 = fopen_check("others.csv", "w");

    fscanf(in, "%*[\n]");  // skip initial empty lines

    while (fscanf(in, "%79[^\n]%*[\n]", line) == 1) {
        if (strstr(line, "UFO"))
            fprintf(file1, "%s\n", line);
        else
        if (strstr(line, "Disappearance"))
            fprintf(file2, "%s\n", line);
        else
            fprintf(file3, "%s\n", line);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    fclose(file3);
    return 0;
}
```