# reversing audio files using C

Tags: c, audio, reverse, cs50

can someone tell me what have i done wrong in this code. it compiles but it doesn't correctly reverse audio files. It does reverse the file sort of by not correctly that the audio is clear. This is problem set 4 of cs50x course. I belive ther's something wrong at TODO #8.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("entre input and output file names\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2
    char *infile = argv[1];
    char *outfile = argv[2];

    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening file\n");
        fclose(inptr);
        return 2;
    }

    // Read header
    // TODO #3
    WAVHEADER wv;
    fread(&wv, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, inptr);
    long position = ftell(inptr);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4

    if (check_format(wv) == -1)
    {
        printf("input is not a wav.h file\n");
        fclose(inptr);
        return 3;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "wb");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening output file\n");
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        return 4;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&wv, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int blsize = get_block_size(wv);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8
    DWORD bufferSize = wv.subchunk2Size;

    int16_t *audio = malloc(bufferSize);
    fseek(inptr, blsize, SEEK_END);
    fseek(outptr, position, SEEK_SET);

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize / blsize; i++)
    {
        fread(&audio[i], blsize, 1, inptr);
        fseek(inptr, (-2) * blsize, SEEK_CUR);

        fwrite(&audio[i], blsize, 1, outptr);
    }

    fclose(outptr);
    fclose(inptr);
    free(audio);
}

int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    char elmnts[] = {'W', 'A', 'V', 'E', '\0'};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (elmnts[i] != header.format[i])
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    int blsize = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
    return blsize;
}
```

i don't know what to do. please help.

Comment: `fopen(infile, "r");` and `fopen(outfile, "wb");`... Can you spot something not quite right? And, think carefully about where the file pointer is for the first `fread()` of the data...

Comment: Although it does not solve your problem I wonder why you close files if the pointers to them are null! ;) https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674233/17820208

Comment: You probably also need to swap the contents of the block you read from the source file before writing it to the target file! (pay attention to the data dimension of the elements into the block)

Comment: Your code includes some improvement points as Fe2O3 suggests, but it still works well with
the bundled `input.wav` just by fixing "r" to "rb". Another (minor) correction is
`fseek(inptr, -blsize, SEEK_END);` just before the `for` loop.
(Please note the minus sign), It does not affect the sound quality but makes sense
in binary comparison of output files.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some commentary added to regions of your code:

```
#include <stdint.h> // Will not be needed

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /* ... */
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r"); // Windows requires "rb"
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening file\n");
        fclose(inptr); // open didn't succeed. No need for fclose()
        return 2;
    }

    /* ... */
    long position = ftell(inptr); // unnecessary
    /* ... */

    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "wb"); // Good! "binary"
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("error opening output file\n");
        fclose(outptr); // unnecessary
        fclose(inptr); // good!
        return 4;
    }
    fwrite(&wv, sizeof(WAVHEADER), 1, outptr); // Good!

    /* ... */

    DWORD bufferSize = wv.subchunk2Size; // DWORD = 32bit unsigned

    int16_t *audio = malloc(bufferSize); // why int16_t? Guessing?
    fseek(inptr, blsize, SEEK_END);
    fseek(outptr, position, SEEK_SET); // unnecessary

    for (int i = 0; i < bufferSize / blsize; i++)
    {
        fread(&audio[i], blsize, 1, inptr); // why only 1 sample each time?
        fseek(inptr, (-2) * blsize, SEEK_CUR); // Good try!
        fwrite(&audio[i], blsize, 1, outptr);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

To open a binary file, especially on Windows, use "rb" (or "wb" as you did!).

No harm, but don't `close()` files that weren't successfully opened.

You allocate a region capable of holding all the samples in the file, then read/write each sample individually involving a lot of `fseek()` that seems mysterious. There's a simpler way!

```
    size_t bufferSize = (size_t)wv.subchunk2Size; // for big numbers

    char *audio = malloc( bufferSize ); // ptr to individual bytes
    /* omitting verification for brevity */

    fread( audio, 1, bufferSize, inptr ); // load everything!
    fclose( inptr ); // finished with input file, thanks

    char *smpl = audio + bufferSize; // point 1 byte beyond end of buffer

    // Now, skip BACKWARDS through the buffer, one sample at a time
    while( (smpl -= blsize) >= audio )
        fwrite( smpl, 1, blsize, outptr ); // and output each sample
    // then close the output file and free the allocated block
```

I hope this helps you understand how to make use of the facilities of C and utilise available dynamic memory.

(You should add some more validation that `fread()` loaded all that was requested, and each `fwrite()` worked properly, too.)

Comment: they are using fseek because thats what the current CS50 lesson taught them to do. it didn't teach them about how to interact with the FileHandle pointer at all.  this is all very good feedback but it is noteworthy they have deviated from the problem a bit, the int16_t choice inparticular has no basis and should have been a char.   Theres also a latent problem here if the audio is stereo and the fact that they never checked the bitsPerSample to calculate bytes per sample; but possible they did reading the subchunk2size was useful for some reason.

Comment: @UpAndAdam Thank you for the elaboration, especially that this is an `fseek()` exercise for the course. Since this is SO, and not a CS50 forum, one does what one can to help the OP... I appreciate the extra info (not previously revealed by questions posted on this site.) Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I learnt my mistakes and I'll change my code.

Comment: no problem @Fe2O3 I still think your answer is great and upvoted it. it shows them another way to go about it that feels more natural. I had forgotten myself that you could do that with the FILE*. So a very good and useful answer. just wanted to explain why they were using fseek so much.  I actually think the problem is really silly the way they set the whole thing up.  They make you obtain the block size = bytesPerSample * numChannels, but in it's just bytesPerSample is a Sample/Block. all you have to do is write the blocks in reverse order and handle going back by 2 at a time if stereo.