# Do operations such as fwrite and fread have undefined behavior when stream is null?

Tags: posix, system-calls, c11

I'm specifically looking for the word in the C11 standard (ISO/IEC 9899:2011), or a POSIX page. I checked the [POSIX manual for fwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html) out, but it doesn't mention *undefined behavior* at all. However, the [manual for fclose](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fclose.html) does say that

> After the call to fclose(), any use of stream results in undefined behavior.

But I still don't see whether a `NULL` stream causes UB.

Comment: 7.1.4p1 applies unless overridden and it is not overridden for `fread` or `fwrite`

Comment: Behavior can be undefined even it is not mentioned explicitly to be so. Take the term "undefined" verbally, something is undefined if it is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `fread()` and `fwrite()` expect the *stream* argument to be a value returned by a successful call to `fopen()`, `fdopen()` or `freopen()`. Since those functions return NULL on error, the *stream* argument cannot be NULL.

Since the manual page does not say what happens when *stream* is not a value returned by a successful call to `fopen()` etc. this means that the manual page does not say what happens when *stream* is not a value returned by a successful call to `fopen()` etc., or, in other words, the behavior is not defined.

See also the accepted answer to the question "[Why glibc's fclose(NULL) cause segmentation fault instead of returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922871/why-glibcs-fclosenull-cause-segmentation-fault-instead-of-returning-error)" on this board.