# How to check a file is opened or not if i forgot to assign null to file pointer

Tags: c, file-io

I have opened a file

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
fclose(fp);
```

scenario is that  I forgot to assign null to `fp`
Now I want to check whether this file is open or not using same `fp` pointer

Comment: Ummm... don't forget to null out the pointer?

Comment: Do not try to hide the problem. Fix it correctly and do the NULL assignment after the `fclose`.

Comment: Although, you can do what you're after

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a given file descriptor stored in a variable is still valid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340695/how-to-check-if-a-given-file-descriptor-stored-in-a-variable-is-still-valid)

Comment: also the recommendation from the previous comment has a problem. If the pointer is not initialized, it might point to a valid file pointer (left over from a previous call as stack residue).

Comment: Unfortunately, the stdio functions dereference the pointer, and expect it to point to a valid (though *logically* opaque) file stream structure. You have a dangling pointer, and there's no portable way to determine if it points to a valid object, or even addressable memory.

Answer (score 6):

You can't. The value of `fp` after closing it is indeterminate: http://www.iso-9899.info/n1256.html#7.19.3p4

This means any operation on it results in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

this might help `--->`

```
if(fp == NULL)
   printf("Error in file opening\n")
```

Comment: How does this tell you whether the value of `fp` was passed to `fclose()`?

Comment: error check .. dont need to call close if the file hasnt open

Answer (score 1):

Using fopen() returned pointer after closing it is indeterminate.

Instead if you use open() system call you can access using the fd to check if it open or not in /proc folder

**/proc**  contains all the details regarding the process. you can access the current process using /proc/self 
inside which is a file fd  **/proc/self/fd**
each file in there is named after a fd.

(Use **g_dir_open**, **g_dir_read_name** and **g_dir_close** to do the listing)

Answer (score 0):

If file not open then `fopen` return null to `fp`. Null check after `fopen()`. Assign NULL after `fclose`.

In your case you can check file open or not by checking `fp` to NULL.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
if (fp == NULL) {
      printf("not open\n");
      return -1 ;
}
else
      printf("File open\n");

if(fp != NULL) {
    fclose(fp);
    fp = NULL;
}
```

> Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.

[What happens to FILE pointer after file is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441059/what-happens-to-file-pointer-after-file-is-closed)