# fileno for closed file

Tags: c, file, file-io, fopen

I have a function like this which aims to read a file:

`int foo(FILE* f)`

I want to use `flock` in order to prevent TOCTTOU. `flock` requires a file descriptor as an integer. I can get this using `fileno(file)`. The implementation of `foo` therefore might look like this:

```
int foo(FILE* f) {
  if(!f) return -1;
  int fd = fileno(f);
  if(fd < 0) return -1;
  flock(fd, LOCK_EX);
  //do all the reading stuff and so on.
}
```

However, the evil user might do something like this:

```
FILE* test;
test = fopen("someexistingfile.txt", "r");
fclose(test);
foo(test);
```

Then I have a problem because `fileno` will do invalid reads according to valgrind because it assumes that the file is open.

Any ideas on how to check whether the file is closed?

Comment: "*evil user*"? Well, I'd say "stupid" user.

Comment: Check the return value of `flock()`. I strongly assume that it fails if `fd` is not a valid descriptor.

Comment: @MartinR well problem is, `fileno` already gives invalid read if file is closed

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/21450109/694576 if not a duplicate to (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21450247/694576 to it).

Comment: In particular file descriptors are opaque numbers that only mean anything to the kernel, if they are invalid (e.g. you just randomly pick a number and try to do an operation on it) it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: "*check for fclose*" why? I mean how would this help to manoeuvre around the issue the OP is facing?

Comment: Woopse fumbly fingers, I meant to type `flock` :P  @alk, thank you for pointing it out. 

check for `flock` returning a -1 and check errno to see what went wrong. See `flock(2)` Return Value for details. It does set errno to -EBADF upon trying to lock an unopened file descriptor.

Comment: @AhmedMasud as already pointed out in the post, `fileno()` is the problem because it causes invalid read...the problem is the invalid read.

Comment: I'm wondering what kind of TOCTOU bug you're worried about.  And there's another problem - a quite possible result of the undefined behavior of using `fileno()` on a closed `FILE *` is you get a file descriptor that refers to another file entirely.

Comment: I'm confused why this was downvoted. While OP has a fundamental misunderstanding of resource handles and why what they're asking for is impossible, I find it a *common misunderstanding*, and the question is stated clearly and reasonable to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[C11 n1570 7.21.3p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p4)

> 4. A file may be disassociated from a controlling stream by closing the file. Output streams are flushed (any unwritten buffer contents are transmitted to the host environment) before the stream is disassociated from the file. **The value of a pointer to a `FILE` object is *indeterminate after the associated file is closed*** (including the standard text streams). Whether a file of zero length (on which no characters have been written by an output stream) actually exists is implementation-defined.

After `fclose` the use of the value of a `FILE *` in library functions leads to undefined behaviour. The value of the pointer cannot be used safely for anything at all until reassigned.

In other words, you cannot do really *anything at all* to discern whether the `FILE *` value you've given refers to a valid open file or not... well except for testing against `NULL` - if the value of the pointer is `NULL` it certainly cannot point to an open stream.