# c++ files array messes up my variable

Tags: c++

My programme keeps producing a segmentation fault.
I have simplified my code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void open_file(FILE** file)
{
        *file = fopen("test" , "wb");
        return;
}


int main ()
{
    int Tracks = 1;
    FILE* Files;
    int i = 1;

    Files = new FILE[Tracks + 1];

    printf("i = %d\n", i); //i = 1
    open_file(&Files + i);

    printf("i = %d\n", i); /i = 0
    fclose(*(&Files + i)); //Segmentation fault

    return 0;
}
```

I must be doing some really stupid pointer-error, but to me my pointer-arithmetics operations look fine... The problem is, that for some magic reason, the variable i changes its value to 0. Could someone explain to me why??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must remove `FILE* Files`. And edit `FILE **Files=new...`

Comment: Looks more like C than C++ (other than the `new`).

Comment: @crashmstr, what's your point? It's still C++.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use e.g. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: @dfeuer yes, it may still be C++ but it is not idiomatic (i.e. "natural") C++. If one is learning C++, it can be better to learn modern C++ using `std::string`, `std::vector` and not writing it as ["A Better C"](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq.html#difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen` return a FILE*, so you may want to use an array of FILE* or a FILE** to store many of it.

Also you have to check the file to be opened before closing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void open_file(FILE** file)
{
    *file = fopen("test" , "wb");
    return;
}    

int main ()
{
    int Tracks = 1;
    FILE** Files = new FILE*[Tracks + 1];
    int i = 1;

    printf("i = %d\n", i); //i = 1
    open_file(&Files[i]);  // Will write at the address of the i-th element of Files.

    printf("i = %d\n", i); //i = 1

    // This have to be done for each element that correspond to an open file.
    // Add a for-loop should be considered.
    if (Files[i])          // Avoid segmentation fault
    {
        fclose(Files[i]);
        Files[i] = 0;      // So I know it is closed.
    }

    delete[] Files;
    return 0;
}
```

About the `Files[i] = 0;` you can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441059/what-happens-to-file-pointer-after-file-is-closed).

About the *magic* `i` modification.
Here what happens :

```
void open_file(FILE** file)
{
    // Write file address or 0 at the given address.
    *file = fopen("test" , "wb");
    return;
}    

int main ()
{
    int Tracks = 1;
    FILE* Files = new FILE[Tracks + 1];  // Files at address a
    int i = 1;                           // i probably at address a + sizeof(FILE*)

    printf("i = %d\n", i); // i = 1

    // here i = 1 so &Files + i = &Files + 1 = address of i.
    open_file(&Files + i); // Call to open_file with the address of i !

    // open_file failed and write 0 to the given address.
    printf("i = %d\n", i); // i = 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening answer!

Comment: just one more question, is this how i should delete the pointer-array:
delete [] *Files;

Comment: @HeinrichHeine, indeed you should delete the **full array**, like this : `delete[] Files;`. Each element of the array have to be closed.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is one of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), where the address-of operator have higher precedence than the addition operator. That means you are doing e.g. `(&Files) + i`, which is equivalent to `(&Files)[i]`.

Comment: It is wrong either way.  (&Files)[i] is wrong because only i=0 is valid.  &Files[i] is wrong because it would cause a type mismatch.  This answer is incorrect.  The type of (&Files)[i] and type of &Files[i] are different.  The problem is because the entire program is screwed up.  Why in the world would open_file not just return FILE*...  There is also no need to new FILE.  fopen does that for you.

Comment: It does (in an implicit way) answers why the variable i could be changed.

Comment: @stefaanv, it doesn't.  The answer to why i could change is because (&Files)[1] points to the memory address occupied by i.  I suspect the original poster knows that &Files + i is the same as (&Files)[i].  It's must be super implicit...