# updating file pointer via other function

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void hello(FILE * fp)
{ 
    if( ( fp = fopen("log","r") ) == NULL)
        printf("%s", "Error opening file");
}

void main()
{
    char p;
    FILE *sf=fopen("prac.txt","r");
    hello(sf);

    p=fgetc(sf);
    printf("%c",p);
}
```

I wanted to change the file pointer `sf` to point to file `log` via `hello` function but `printf` is still printing the content of `prac.txt` file.

Comment: you need a second argument to your `hello`, such as `string filename`

Comment: Your code is pure C, I removed the C++ tag. C and C++ are **not** the same language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I modify a pointer that has been passed into a function in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766893/how-do-i-modify-a-pointer-that-has-been-passed-into-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change what the `FILE*` points to, you need to pass a `FILE**`. Before you change it, you need to ensure that any file it happens to be pointing to is closed. This also relies on you always setting `FILE*` variables to NULL after `fclose` (this, alas, does not happen automatically), so there's a decent chance careless use of this function would call `fclose` on an already-closed `FILE*`. But this is probably still better than willfully leaking file descriptors and not flushing files.

```
void hello(FILE **fp)
{
  // This is actually a horrible test. And in general, this is not
  // something you should do, but it is better than leaking open
  // file descriptors, so, yeah, 
  if (*fp != NULL) {
    fclose(*fp);
    *fp = NULL;
    printf("Closed file.");
  }
  if( (*fp = fopen("log","r") == NULL) {
    printf("%s", "Error opening file");
  }
}
```

Comment: why closing is required?

Comment: @enamel Couple of reasons. Data that has been "written" (but is still buffered by the program) may get lost. "Open files" is a very limited resource, so you should not waste them. And if you over-write a FILE* like that, you have absolutely no way of being able to close it, or flush it, afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In `void hello(FILE *fp)`, `fp` only exists in the scope of the function `hello` (the value of the pointer is copied when you call the function and it's destroyed at the end of the func).

This works:

```
#include<stdio.h>

FILE* hello(FILE * fp)
{ 
    fclose(fp);
    if( ( fp = fopen("log","r") ) == NULL) {
        printf("%s", "Error opening file");
        return NULL;
    }
    return fp;
}

void main()
{
    char p;
    FILE *sf=fopen("prac.txt","r");
    sf = hello(sf);

    if (sf != NULL) 
    {
        p=fgetc(sf);
        printf("%c",p);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you ..... why we require this fclose(fp)? ............ i was trying to update the 'sf' pointer address by call by reference

Comment: Read the answer of Adam Rosenfield for fclose : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175827/what-happens-if-i-dont-call-fclose-in-a-c-program. Another point, here you don't update the sf pointer address, you update directly a copy of the sf pointer. When you call by reference, you have to send the address of your variable. If your variable is a pointer, you have to send a pointer of pointer. Here sf is `FILE*` and it address type is `FILE**` (see Vatine's solution)

Answer (score 0):

you should close the file before reopning it

```
#include<stdio.h>
void hello(FILE ** fp)
{ 
 fclose(*fp);
if( ( *fp = fopen("log","r") ) == NULL)
  printf("%s", "Error opening file");    
}

void main()
{
 char p;
 FILE *sf=fopen("prac.txt","r");
 hello(&sf);

 p=fgetc(sf);
 printf("%c",p);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441059/what-happens-to-file-pointer-after-file-is-closed
fp is null after fclose , fopen givs a new fp

Comment: Erm, no, `fclose` does not change `*fp`, so "is it NULL` is merely a convention.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you copy arguments. You do not override the content of the file pointer only the local copy of the address.

The file pointer itself is not updated. To archive this either pass a pointer to a pointer to the function and dereference accordingly or return the new file pointer and override the old one. Anyways care for closing the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
// Use double pointer since fp is getting address of a pointer variable
void hello(FILE ** fp)
{ 
    // If the file is already pointing to some file then close that file
    if(*fp != NULL)
    {
        fclose(*fp); 
        *fp = NULL;
    }
    if( ( *fp = fopen("log","r") ) == NULL)
        printf("%s", "Error opening file");
}

int main()
{
    char p;
    FILE *sf=fopen("prac.txt","r");
    // While sending the file pointer you need to send the address of the file pointer
    hello(&sf);

    p=fgetc(sf);
    printf("%c",p);

    return 0;
}
```